# Subsetting questionnaire Data with multiple conditions

Tags: r, conditional-statements, subset, psych

I have a set of questionnaire data of about 800 participants incorporating over 100 questions in total. To further discover single parts of this dataset, I want to create a subset in R that holds only data of those participants who have no NA in the ca. 20 questions I am particularly interested in (making this a subset of 20 conditions). I have tried

`datasubset<-subset(complete_data, Question1!="NA", Question2!="NA",...)`

but somehow R can't process more than two conditions at a time with this command, claiming it did not find Object number 3, whichever Question/ condition it is that I put third. I can't use separate lines of code because the newest one would replace the one before. Is there a different way of implicating multiple conditions?

Also: A few of the commands I need this subset for are from the `psych` package, which is sensitive to NAs. Is there a way around this sensitivity without using listwise deletion?

As a reference example, this is the complete mtcars dataset.

````
                mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt qsec vs am gear carb
Fiat X1-9      27.3   4  79.0  66   NA 1.935 18.9  1  1    4    1
Porsche 914-2  26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.7  0  1    5    2
Lotus Europa   30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.9  1  1    5    2
Ford Pantera L 15.8   8 351.0 264   NA 3.170 14.5  0  1    5    4```

My Goal is to delete all participants (i.e. cars) that have missing values between the columns "hp" and "wt", while keeping all columns in the dataset. The final dataset I am looking for would, in mtcars, look like this:

```mt
                mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt qsec vs am gear carb

Porsche 914-2  26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.7  0  1    5    2
Lotus Europa   30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.9  1  1    5    2```

If there had been missing values in other columns, e.g. "cyl", this would not have changed the output in the solution I am looking for.

I want to use this new dataset mainly for descriptive statistics as a side exploration project, such as:

```library(psych)
describe(dat$Item)```
which would produce an output like this:

```vars   n mean   sd median trimmed  mad min max range skew kurtosis   se
   1    630 2.09 0.75      2     2.1 1.48   1   4     3 0.05    -0.79 0.03```
````

Comment: Are you looking for something like `data %>% drop_na(hp:wt)` using the `tidyr` package?

Comment: No I am looking to still have all variables available in the final dataset, just without participants who have missing within a certain set of those variables, this solution provides a new dataset with only the specified variables.

Answer (score 0):

Even without an example it's easy to filter out NAs with `complete.cases`.

```
mt
                mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt qsec vs am gear carb
Fiat X1-9      27.3   4  79.0  66   NA 1.935 18.9  1  1    4    1
Porsche 914-2  26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.7  0  1    5    2
Lotus Europa   30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.9  1  1    5    2
Ford Pantera L 15.8   8 351.0 264   NA 3.170 14.5  0  1    5    4

mt[complete.cases(mt),1:6]
               mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt
Porsche 914-2 26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140
Lotus Europa  30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513
```

Comment: That does not work for  me as in your example it shows only those six variables while I would need to still see the whole dataset, just stripped of those participants who have missing values on the variables I specified. So, for example, I have 400 variables in my dataset, I want to exclude everyone who has missing values between the variables 300 and 320, but still be able to work with all 400 variables.

Comment: @valtur If you could include an example and expected output would make it easier to give a more precise answer. E.g maybe a transpose of the data let’s you exclude slides of questions or participants, which in turn preserves observations for others.

Comment: My dataset is too big to make sense here, but I will show what I mean in mtcars in a separate comment!

Comment: @valtur Better put it in the question body for everyone to see. Comments may shift and not everyone may necessarily see it. See here how to make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).